# How to limit the number of total animated drop cubes and make them animate by their added order?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

When we click this add button we will add a new cube which will drop immediately, but if we click it very quickly, there will be too many cubes dropping. I want to limit the number of the total animated dropping cube.

For example, even if we click the button very quickly and 10 cubes are added to the page, only two cubes are dropping, and others must wait until they finished.

For example, the 3rd and 4th cubes will start to drop when cube 1 and cube 2 finished.

I was thinking maybe we can have a global variable of the total animated cubes count, ++ and -- it when a new cube is starting and finishing animation, use setInterval to check if the variable is less than 2, but this can't make the animation based on the cubes created order. May I know how to solve this? Thank you so much!

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('add');
var container = document.getElementById('cubes-container');
var cubeId = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', addCube);

var currentAnimateCount = 0;

function dropCube(cube) {
  var pos = 0;
  let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (pos == 200) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
      pos++;
      cube.style.top = pos + "px";

    }
  }, 1);

}

function addCube() {
  let cube = document.createElement('div');
  let cubeContainer = document.createElement('div');
  cube.className = 'cube';
  cube.id = cubeId;
  cube.innerHTML = cube.id;
  cubeId++;
  cubeContainer.className = 'cube-container';
  cubeContainer.append(cube);
  container.append(cubeContainer);
  let pos = 0;
  dropCube(cube)


}
```

```css
#cubes-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.cube-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.cube {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add new</button>
<div id="cubes-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, how many cubes are you happy to have waiting, and aslo do you remove them (delete them) at some point? You may find looking at CSS animation helpful as well.

Comment: @AHaworth @A Haworth Hi! Thank you so much for your reply! I want at most only two cubes are animating, all others are waiting. If I click the add button very quickly, I may add 10 cubes at the same time, but only the first two are dropping, after they finishing, cube 3 and 4 start dropping, then after cube 3 and 4 finishing, cube 5 and 6 start dropping. even at the same time I keep clicking the add button, they always follow this order. I don't plan to delete them at some point now.

Comment: Don't let it go on too long then else you may run out of store if you keep creating but not deleting (will take a long time though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example. It is using jQuery versus JavaScript. It could be similarly scripted.

```js
$(function() {
  function addCube(target) {
    var i = $(".cube").length;
    var container = $("<div>", {
      class: "cube-container"
    }).appendTo(target);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "cube",
      id: "cube-" + i
    }).html(i).appendTo(container);
    return container;
  }

  function dropCube(cube) {
    $(cube).addClass("falling").animate({
      top: "200px"
    }, 2000, function() {
      $(cube).removeClass("falling");
      if (cubes.length && $(".falling").length < 2) {
        dropCube(cubes.shift());
      }
    });
  }

  var cubes = [];

  $("#add").click(function() {
    cubes.push(addCube("#cubes-container"));
    if ($(".falling").length < 2) {
      dropCube(cubes.shift());
    }
  });
});
/*
var btn = document.getElementById('add');
var container = document.getElementById('cubes-container');
var cubeId = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', addCube);

var currentAnimateCount = 0;

function dropCube(cube) {
  var pos = 0;
  let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (pos == 200) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
      pos++;
      cube.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }, 1);

}

function addCube() {
  let cube = document.createElement('div');
  let cubeContainer = document.createElement('div');
  cube.className = 'cube';
  cube.id = cubeId;
  cube.innerHTML = cube.id;
  cubeId++;
  cubeContainer.className = 'cube-container';
  cubeContainer.append(cube);
  container.append(cubeContainer);
  let pos = 0;
  dropCube(cube)
}
*/
```

```css
#cubes-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.cube-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.cube {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add new</button>
<div id="cubes-container"></div>
```

Using an Array, you cna `.shift()` the first item of the array. Also adding a Class to the falling items allows you to keep a count of which ones are falling. I like to use Animate since it allows for a callback when the animation is done, so you can check for the next item.

**Update for JavaScript**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('add');
var container = document.getElementById('cubes-container');
var cubes = [];
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  cubes.push(addCube());
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("falling").length < 2) {
    dropCube(cubes.shift());
  }
});

function dropCube(cube) {
  var pos = 0;
  cube.classList.add("falling");
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (pos == 200) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      cube.classList.remove("falling");
      if (document.getElementsByClassName("falling").length < 2 && cubes.length) {
        dropCube(cubes.shift());
      }
    } else {
      pos++;
      cube.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }, 1);
}

function addCube() {
  let cube = document.createElement('div');
  let cubeContainer = document.createElement('div');
  cube.className = 'cube';
  cube.id = document.getElementsByClassName("cube").length;
  cube.innerHTML = cube.id;
  cubeContainer.className = 'cube-container';
  cubeContainer.append(cube);
  container.append(cubeContainer);
  return cubeContainer;
}
```

```css
#cubes-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.cube-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.cube {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add new</button>
<div id="cubes-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That array method is amazing! If I use pure javaScript and things like setInterval, is there a way to know which ones finish falling animation and trigger others to drop?

Comment: @xixi I went back and made a JS example too. jQuery is simply a Framework for JavaScript, so if you can do it in jQuery; you can write it back to JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I can't vote because it says I "need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote", but I clicked "accept this answer". Really thank you so much! This method is amazing! why can't I come up with such amazing methods~ I really need to learn more about how to use JavaScript properly! Thank you!

Comment: @xixi there are lots of good tutorials and ways to learn more scripting methods. You will also see a lot of good examples on Stack Overflow. Soon, you will start seeing where you can improve code and understand how to use it better.

Comment: Thank you so much Twisty :D I'll try to learn more about front end!